# The importance of Schur-Zassenhaus theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I've just studied the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem ([here there is the statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem)), but I don't understand its importance in the theory of finite groups. Wikipedia for example says:

> The Schur–Zassenhaus theorem at least partially answers the question:
>   "In a composition series, how can we classify groups with a certain
>   set of composition factors?"

but for me it's not clear what does it means.

Comment: Do you know what a composition series and composition factor is?

Comment: Yes I know what they are

Answer (score 3):

If you know the composition factors consist of the sequence of simple groups $H_1,...,H_n$ with the orders of the groups relatively prime, then you know that the original group must be some chained a chained semi-direct product of those simple groups.

It's certainly not extremely helpful, since the composition factors are simple groups, and the non-commutative simple groups are all of even order. so for this condition to hold, at most one of the $H_i$ can be non-commutative.